# SignalR - connection.start failed

Tags: javascript, azure, signalr, azure-functions

I try to run the tutorial from **Anthony Chu**.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4d0wor7uAgQ

He implemented a "SimpleChat-Application" with Azure CosmosDB, Azure Functions and SignalR. Where you can send messages between Clients in Realtime.
I tried different settings and version but i can´t make it work.

**Source Code in my "index.html": (JavaScript)**

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@aspnet/signalr@1.0.0-rc1-final/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    const apiBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:7071';
    const hubName = 'chat';
    getConnectionInfo().then(info => {      
      let username;
      while (!username && username !== null) {
        username = prompt('Enter a username');
      }
      console.log(info.accessTokenFactory);
      if (username === null) return;
      document.body.classList.add('ready');
      const messageForm = document.getElementById('message-form');
      const messageBox = document.getElementById('message-box');
      const messages = document.getElementById('messages');
      const options = {
        accessTokenFactory: () => info.accessKey
      };

      const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(info.url, options)
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
        .build();

      connection.onclose(() => console.log('disconnected'));

      console.log('retrieving messages');

      getMessage().then(messages => {
        for(let m of messages) {
          newMessage(m);
        }
        console.log('connecting...');
        connection.start()
          .then(() => console.log('connected!'))
          .catch(console.error);
      });
      console.log('connected after');
    }).catch(alert);
    
    function getConnectionInfo() {
      console.log("test");
      return axios.post(`${apiBaseUrl}/api/negotiate`)
        .then(resp => resp.data);
    }

    function getMessage(sender, messageText) {
      return axios.get(`${apiBaseUrl}/api/getmessage`).then(resp => resp.data);
    }

    function newMessage(message) {
      const newMessage = document.createElement('li');
      newMessage.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${message.sender}: ${message.text}`));
      messages.prepend(newMessage);
    }
  </script>
```

**Source Code (negotiate - function.json)**

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "signalRConnectionInfo",
      "name": "connectionInfo",
      "hubName": "chat",
      "connectionStringSetting": "AzureSignalRConnectionString", 
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Source Code (negotiate - index.js)**

```
module.exports = function (context, req, connectionInfo) {
    context.res = { body: connectionInfo };
    context.done();
}
```

I can receive data from the cosmosDB but when i come to the connection.start() method... it didn´t connect to the Service?!

Can anybody help me?

Many Thanks!!!

**Versions:**

- Func(2.2.70)
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService (1.0.0-preview1-10002)
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB (3.0.2)
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator (1.0.1)

("Me: Hallo" is an entry in the CosmosDB)

[Result Page with Console-Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHCOP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Take care in this section of the code...**

```
      const options = {
        accessTokenFactory: () => info.accessKey
      };

      const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(info.url, options)
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
        .build();
```

change

```
=> info.accessKey
```

and insert

```
=> info.accessToken
```

The connection failed, because of the undefined value!